# How do I send the HTML form to the email without opening the outlook mail?

Tags: java, php

How do I send the HTML form to the email without opening the outlook mail?
The form will automatically send to the email that I want without open the email.

Must I use PHP? Cause as I use PHP it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't send email from the client side (Browser), you will have to expose a URL from PHP to which form is submitted and from PHP you will be able to send email.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. what URL to use from php?   
I tried to use this code and also a php file but it's not working. 

   <form method="POST" name="equiry_form" action="scripts/customer_enquiry.php">
    <label for="firstName">First Name:*</label>

Answer (score 0):

You must configure smtp in your php server for mail function to work in PHP.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. may i ask do you know how to configure smtp in the php server?

Comment: Which operating system do you use ?

Comment: i use windows os

Comment: when you type this  `echo mail ("borutflis1@gmail.com" ,"testmailfunction" , "Oj",$headers);` what does it print ?

Comment: it print this:

Thank you! Your message has been sent.

"; } echo mail ("borutflis1@gmail.com" ,"testmailfunction" , "Oj",$headers); ?>

Comment: did you check spam folder ?

Comment: yes, i check the spam folder but there's isn't anything

Comment: try to put this in php.ini you should change value according to you  `[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = someonelse@example.com`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this for implementing your requirement
http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php
Also you need to configure your PHP to send emails if you are running on a local server.

Comment: hi thanks for your email, and the information. may i ask how to configure php to send emails?

Comment: Where you are running your code? On a remote server or localhost?

Comment: on a remote sever using dreamwaver

Comment: Please use this PHP-Mailer module in your application
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer